# Auto mount Google cloud computing disk in Centos (using /etc/fstab)

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine, mount

I'm currently setting up a server @ Google Cloud computing, everything works fine except I'm having problems automatically mount the secondary disk to the system.

I'm running centos 6 / cloudlinux 6. I can mount to secondary disk without problems after boot with the following command:
"mount /dev/sdb /data"

Please find below the log of /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=6c782ac9-0050-4837-b65a-77cb8a390772 / ext4    defaults,barrier=0 1 1
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
UUID=10417d68-7e4f-4d00-aa55-4dfbb2af8332 / ext4        default         0 0
```

log of df -h: (*after manual mount)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.8G  1.2G  8.2G  13% /
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb         99G   60M   94G   1% /data
```

Thank you already in advance,

~ Luc

Answer (score 4):

Our provisioning scripts look something like this for our secondary disks:

```
# Mount the appropriate disk
sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" /dev/sdb /your_path

# Add disk UID to fstab
DISK=$(sudo blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdb)
echo "UUID=$DISK /your_path a ext4 defaults 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! will try this in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks for the help, I forgot the /data part in /etc/fstab/ I now have:

[code]
/dev/sdb                /data                   ext4    defaults   0 0
[/code]

Comment: keep in mind that `safe_format_and_mount` command will format the disk. so, if you have data on your secondary disk use the `mount` command instead.

Comment: @Kamran safe format and mount only formats the disk if its unformatted: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#formatting

Comment: @Jasse, if you're mounting a formatted data disk, I recommend using the `mount` command, as there is no point to check if the disk is formatted every time the VM instance is restarted.

Comment: @Kamran very true. However, I just wanted to point out that the command doesn't format the disk if it doesn't need to.

Comment: The safe_format_and_mount command is now obsolete, and not included on recent Google VM images.